# How can we share a state variables between two React components on the same page?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-component

I have two components within App.js. The main `App` component (that contains a basic form) and a custom `TextInput` component. I understand that ideally, it would be better to have separate files. However, I am trying to keep this as brief and simple as possible.

Anyway, I declare a state variable with `const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);` within the first component and would like to use this within the second component. I tried declaring the variable outside of both components to enable sharing, but that didn't work. How should I go about doing this? I mean normally, I would just export and import, but here, both components are on the same page.

Comment: Define state in App.js and share between component by using props

Comment: it needs to be in a parent component that is using both of them, in other words the state needs to be higher up in tree.

Comment: @HareshMakwana I will be scouring the internet, but do you have any short and sweet examples of this? Especially, for components on the same page?

Comment: Note that if this solution is simpler for sharing a single state, for sharing multiple states across multiple components, it is better to use the store pattern. See `redux`, `mobx`, or simply react context sharing: https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Comment: @StéphaneVeyret Aah okay. I will look into that, thanks.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, if you have given a pascal case naming for the text input such as `function TextInput(){...}` , then react will consider this as a separate component even if this is defined in the same file. This is why the state variables of the `App` component are not within the scope of `TextInput`

You can mitigate this by following either of the following approcahes,

- Make text input a normal function which returns the JSX

```
function textInput(){
 // the state variable 'success' and 'setSuccess' will be normally accessible here
 return(
   <div>
      <input type="text" />
   <div>
 )
}

//return for the 'App' component

return(
   <>
     {textInput()}
   </>
)
```

- Passing the state as `props` to the `TextInput` component

  If you follow this approach, then you can have the `TextInput` component in a separate file as well

```
//parent 'App' component

function App(){
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);

  return(
    <>
       <TextInput success={success} setSuccess={setSuccess}></TextInput>
    </>
  )
}

function TextInput(props){
   const {success, setSuccess} = props;
   
   // In here you can refer success and setSuccess normally as you would even if this is in a separate file
}
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much for the elaboration. However, apart from using props... Isn't there a simpler way to share between the components that are on the same page?

Comment: Because, in my case, I have not one instance of `TextInput` but many instances of `TextInput` within `App`... So, would I have to "resend" success with every instance of TextInput? Seems like a redundant thing to do, as the variable `success` measures the success of not the individual instance, but the combined success of all the instances. It seems weird to send the same value through each of the `TextInput` instances!

Comment: I am not getting a clear picture of your setup, so it might be helpful if you can share your actual code. If there are multiple components, then I believe that the only way in react to share the states is by binding it to the `props`. If it is a dynamic and complex application which you are building, then you can also have a look at react `context` api or `redux` to have a global and unified state tree which can be shared between all components no matter the hierarchy

Comment: @ItAssistors I was going through multiple posts and this answer finally helped me to understand how to pass the state to other components. Passing the method to other components fixed my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To share the state you need to declare the state in the parent component (App in your case) and send it to the child component (TextInput)

e.g.

```
function App() {
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);

  ...

  return (
    <TextInput success={success} setSuccess={setSuccess} />
  );
}
```

```
function TextInput({success, setSuccess}) {
  // use success/setSuccess from props
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the time you've taken to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass props from parent(App component) like :

```
function App() {
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);

  return (
    <TextInput success={success}  />
  );
}
```

and to access it in TextInput component

```
function TextInput(props) {
//Access it using props.success
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the time you've taken to answer this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if maybe I am misunderstanding but...

//App.js

```
function App() {
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);

  return (
    <TextInput success={success}  />
    <FormComponent success={success} /> 
  );
}
```

Comment: And then I assume you mean for me to pick this up from within `TextInput` and `FormComponent` using `props`... Correct?

Comment: local state can only be passed to another component within it's scope...if the component you want to have access to this state is not within it's scope but is a child of one of these components - then yes. you will have to pass it as a prop down to that child. alternatively, you can use global scope with the Context API, or something like redux. That's just the way it works